# mysqldump restore is failing to restore some rows

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database-restore

I'm currently shifting some databases from one server to another and have hit a really annoying issue.

the database is going from an ubuntu 12.04. to a 14.04 machine. Both have the same version of MySQL with pretty much the same config. It's an innodb table.

I backup the database (about 3 gig in size) with mysqldump, scp it to the new server and run the restore. When I then check one table in particular I can see a bunch of missing rows.

I have checked and optimised the table before the back ran.
If I open the dumped sql file I can see the missing rows in it. I can even cut and paste the rows lines and add them back into the database fine - so it's not corrupted data.

I've also tried dumping just the one problem table and re-ordering that on it's own with the same results.

There is nothing in the error logs and I I've also exporting/ importing with heidisql as this gives a nice logs as it goes along hoping to spot an issue. but nothing untoward shows.

Does any one have any thoughts on things to try please.

Comment: were there any errors reported?

Comment: no errors anywhere that I can see

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening due to corrupted indexes,
Try doin a,

```
REPAIR [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL] TABLE
    tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
    [QUICK] [EXTENDED] [USE_FRM]
```

Lookup:
[MySQL 5.1 Repair Table Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html)

and see if the missing rows come back up.

We may have a prior here: [DBA StackExchange: Incomplete mysqldump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7785/incomplete-mysqldump)